# How to let user decide how comments be sorted

Tags: 7, views, theming, comments

The scenario is, in a project comments has a vote up/down field so users can rate a comment. What I'm looking for now is a solution so user can decide if comments should be sorted by date created (newest first) or by its rate (top rated first).
Should I use a views for that? if so how can I hide main comment section?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the most obvious way to manage your user's behavior on comments would be to use **Views**.

And if you want to **hide the main comment section**, you can do so in your content type's parameters (check the comment section of you content type). You'll see stuff like hide and close.

Hope that gives you a start point.